# Powershell import script with parameter

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, import, powershell-4.0

I would like to import my main script in my test script (for unit tests) but with 
`. ("P:\Documents\PS\ppmc_Cronet_Interface.ps1")` or 
 `Import-Module P:\Documents\PS\ppmc_Cronet_Interface.ps1` it automatically executes the main script.

Is there any common way how to handle this? I tried adding a parameter `. ("P:\Documents\PS\ppmc_Cronet_Interface.ps1 -t")` but it won't import the file so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the file file `ppmc_Cronet_Interface.ps1` contain? functions? a module?  please provide more details.

Comment: it contains functions, which i want to test in the other file.

Comment: can you post them here? did you try to enter `function testfunc { echo 'ehlo'}` to a file and dot source it. have you verified the function is not called - e.g. at the end of the file?

Comment: The only way to ***import*** code into a powershell session is to run that code. If ppmc_Cronet_Interface.ps1 contains code other than function definitions, then that code will be executed. If you want to import just functions then put just the functions into their own file. That is a very common way to organize code anyway.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information rather than using comments.

Comment: that makes sense LOL. thanks a lot and sorry i started scripting with powershell this week :/ @EBGreen

Comment: Also, what does the `-t` switch actually do? We are reaching the point where we are going to need to see your code or at least a [MCVE] to really help you.

Comment: should somehow be a flag for testing only (i tried it this way) `if(!$args.Contains("-t"))
{
    Main -Arguments $args
}`

Comment: If you want your code to handle a flag then you need to write that into your code.

Comment: yeah this if statement ist in my main?

Comment: I see. The more canonical powershell way to do this is with a `[switch]` parameter. If you are doing that and the main function is still running then we need to see your actual code to help you sort that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Common Code In Powershell**
You can just put the code you want to include in a different PS1 file, and then "dot source" that file to include it in the current scope:

```
. D:\script_common\MyCode.ps1
```

That's all there is to that.

**Using a Module**
You might consider using a module instead, which can be included using the Import-Module cmdlet. You might have used this to work with things like Active Directory, where you could do something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

In that case, you only need the name of the module because it's in a special directory.

To write your own modules in Powershell, you name the module with a .psm1 extension. Typically, you don't do free floating code in one of these; you write functions which are then available to the code which imports the module.

To import a script module from anywhere, use the full path:

```
Import-Module D:\script_common\MyModule.psm1
```